# Is there a way to show a video in a remoteview notification on Android?

Tags: java, android, video, notifications

I'm working in a notification app for Android and my customer has requested me to insert a video inside the notification preview.

I know that I'm able to create notifications with pictures and notifications with custom views, but when I try to add a video to the custom view my app gives me always this error:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    *Bad notification posted from package com.codeversed.example.Notifications: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.codeversed.example.Notifications user=UserHandle{0} id=0 tag=null score=0 key=0|com.codeversed.example.Notifications|0|null|10008: Notification(pri=0 contentView=com.codeversed.example.Notifications/0x1090089 vibrate=default sound=default defaults=0x7 flags=0x18 color=0x00000000 originalPackageName=N originalUserId=0 vis=PRIVATE))*

I suppose that is it because videos aren't allowed to remote views. Does somebody know if this limitation can be sorted or if there is a way to show videos on notifications?

Regards,

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot show a video in a `Notification`. Partially, that is because `RemoteViews` does not support a `SurfaceView`, `TextureView`, or `VideoView` that you would need. Partially, that is because the party responsible for showing the video may not have rights to do so (e.g., may not have Internet access). Remember that *you* are not the one actually showing the `Notification` — *somebody else* is. You merely provide the specification.

Comment: Many thanks, I will tell it to my customer.

Regards,

Comment: Not sure but it may be possible. I am [searching further about it.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65773220/2289835)