# Show video, gif or banner in push notificaion

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I have come across the notification which **actively changes the content** like banners.
AFAIK videos and GIFs are not supported in the notification.

How can we achieve this?

I have searched and found [Custom Notification Layout](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification) might the solution. But not quite sure.

[image]

Comment: Hello @Rumit Parel, did you achieve this feature. if yes could you please help me

Comment: @simbesi.com, Yes. I shall create a project on GitHub and provide you if possible.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your kind words...I will wait for your sample.

Comment: @simbesi.com, You can have a  [look at this.](https://nishi-emedstore.medium.com/notification-with-image-slider-example-in-android-2758b6d43d38)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RemoteViews](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews).

You can have a look at [this example](https://nishi-emedstore.medium.com/notification-with-image-slider-example-in-android-2758b6d43d38) also.